# insertSubviewBelow not inserting at the correct frame Y offset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIViewController view that I wanted to insert below a subview:

```
[self.view insertSubview:ntVC_.view belowSubview:shareView_];
```

The shareView frame Y is 959 and it's height is 44. So when doing this shouldn't ntVC frame Y be at 1004? However it's at 925 now. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `insertSubview:belowSubview:` refers to the view stack not a view's coordinates.

You need to do the calculation of where to position the view yourself.

```
+-------+         +-------+
|       |         |       |
|  A +-------+    |  A    |----+
|    |       |    |       |    |
+----|  B    |    +-------+    |
     |       |         |   B   |
     +-------+         +-------+
```

In terms of the view stack

- In the example on the left `A` is `below` `B`
- In the example on the right `A` is `above` `B`